# GitHub Pages in docs folder referring files outside docs folder

Tags: javascript, github, github-pages

I have followed GitHub's document and successfully published my project pages using `docs` folder under my project repo. But I'm wondering how could I solve this small problem:

I'm developing a JavaScript library [wesa.js](http://caiyi.us/wesa/), and the source file is stored in `src` folder under the root of the repo. And within my demo website (inside `docs` folder), I want to refer to that source file. However, relatively pathing won't work in this situation once it's published:

Suppose my source file is in `[root]/src/wesa.js`, then if in `[root]/docs/index.html`, I use:

`<script src="../src/wesa.js"></script>`

Once it's published, because my `index.html` would be resolved to:

`mriiiron.github.io/wesa/index.html`

Then, my source file `wesa.js` would be resolved as:

`mriiiron.github.io/src/wesa.js`

which of course points to nothing.

In local environment it works just as I needed, but once it's published to GitHub Pages, there's no way that a Project Page in `docs` folder could refer to any file outside `docs` folder. What I'm doing now is simply keep a physical copy of my source file somewhere inside `docs` folder.

Would there be any trick being my savior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to let your build step also output the final version of the code into the `/docs` folder.

Which is less than you had hoped for, I guess.

Comment: I believe this would work, however currently my work does not need to be built (a JS lib) before using so there's no way I can automate this. Thanks anyway, have a nice night :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to restructure your file tree by placing all your files and subfolders under one project folder.

In this main project folder, you can execute these commands to upload your project to the git repository:

```
git init
git add . 
git commit
```

Take a look at the [git-init](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init) documentation for more information.

---

Your current locations of the files are:

- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mriiiron/wesa/master/docs/index.html
- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mriiiron/wesa/master/src/wesa.js

It should work if you source from the html like so:

```
<script src="../src/wesa.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry I think I haven't got your idea.. Could you explain more?

Comment: @mriiiron I have revised my answer to include more explanation

Comment: Maybe you did not get my question? The problem is that I cannot refer to files outside `docs` folder in my Project Pages. See here: https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.11/user/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/

Comment: This is a question about the GitHub pages feature, not serving raw files from GitHub. (Which is a terribly bad idea anyhow)

Answer (score -1):

I feel ashamed for answering my own question but I can't wait to share this. The perfect solution is from GitHub itself ;) Ah-ha!

[image: Solution]

Comment: how does this solve your problem exactly? i'm attempting to load a file from a directory outside of /docs but have this set - and it's still failing...