# Form submit preventDefault not working on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit, preventdefault

I'm using event.preventDefault on a form submission and it works, but only on desktop devices. When using a mobile device the form is submitted the normal way and the event is not prevented.

Here's what my setup looks like:

index.html

```html
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myForm">
   <input id="name">
   <button type="submit">
</form>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

script.js

```js
$(function() {
    $("#myForm").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let formData = $("#name").val();
        console.log(formData);
});
```

Comment: `<script>` tags belong **inside** either the `<head>` or `<body>`. Yours is outside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was related to a project hosted using GitPages. It turns out that the cause of the problem was that I was trying to reference a script from outside the folder the page was hosted from. The page was hosted from docs/index.html, and I was trying to reference the script using ../dist/script.js

While looking into it more, I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47836883/github-pages-in-docs-folder-referring-files-outside-docs-folder) which says GitPages doesn't allow that since technically only everything in the docs folder is hosted and the dist folder didn't exist. Not sure why it worked only on my computer...

I updated my reference to the script to its jsDelivr URL and everything now works as expected.

Thank you to everyone who offered help!

Answer (score 0):

**The script should have the body tag.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="myForm">
        <input id="name">
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>


    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

`script.js`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on("submit", "#myForm", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let formData = $("#name").val();
    console.log(formData);
    e.target.reset()
  })
})
```

Test Case here:[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/otalibhossain/68vmkcus/1/)

Comment: Hi. Can you explain more on how that would be helpful in resolving this issue?

Comment: Updated. Please check.

Comment: `<script>`, not `<Script>`. Also, OP is using a separate `script.js` file, not inline

Comment: Thank you for the reminder, I put my script tags inside the body. I also tried using $(document).on("submit", "#myForm", function (event)  instead of $("#myForm").submit(function (event) but the result is the same. On my phone, the form is submitted as normal and isn't prevented at all. Weirdly enough, your jsFiddle works properly on my phone and computer. I'm not sure what the difference is between them or what might be causing this.